# How do I return values from one class to another?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, methods, return-value

I just need to return a value which is the savings value back to the call method on the main class. I extended the sub class but it doesn't work. I also tried importing the sub class into the parent class as an object, still no success.

```
package package1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GnX {
   FvX fvx = new FvX( );    
         
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        double price;
        double discount;
        double savings;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
        
        
        System.out.println("Enter a base price for the discount: ");
        price = scan.nextDouble( );
        System.out.println("Now, Enter a discount rate: ");
        discount = scan.nextDouble( );
    
        displayInfo( );
        computeDiscountInfo( );
    
        System.out.println("Special this week on any service over " + price);
        System.out.println("Discount of " + discount);
        System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
    }

    public static void displayInfo( ) {
        System.out.println("Paradise Guitar Is A Fantastic Place To Reherse"); 
        System.out.println("This Rehersal Room Is Studio Based");
    }
}
```

Class that's inherited through parent class in a separate window:

```
package package1;

public class FvX extends GnX {

    public FvX( ) {
    }
    
    public static double computeDiscountInfo(double price, double discount) {
        double savings;
        savings = price * discount / 100;
        return savings;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! so, just to be sure, you meant `computeDiscountInfo( );` in `void Main` doesn't work?

Comment: it's always helpful to clarify what specifically "doesn't work" when asking a question (but it's really common for folks to forget this); eg, what were you expecting, and what did you actually get (which is a good thing to actually define up front before even coding, and is the basis for writing test cases that validate the code)

Comment: Yes through inheritance. It does just fine under the same class but when I extended the class into a sub it gives me problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting to use `computeDiscountInfo`. This belong to the `fvx` object so it should be called as `fvx.computeDiscountInfo(...)`

Now consider

1. it returns a double, so you can do  `double rv = fvx.computeDiscountInfo(...)`
2. you notice that I have wrote `(...)`, because this method takes a couple of paramaters `double price, double discount`.  so you should call using the parameters instead of `...` maybe `double rv = fvx.computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to call the computeDiscountInfo function in the FvX class from your main method.

First create an FvX instance inside your main method and then call the computeDiscountInfo function using that fvx object. You can replace your main class like show below.

```
public class GnX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FvX fvx = new FvX( );

        double price;
        double discount;
        double savings;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter a base price for the discount: ");
        price = scan.nextDouble( );
        System.out.println("Now, Enter a discount rate: ");
        discount = scan.nextDouble( );


        displayInfo( );
        savings = fvx.computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);


        System.out.println("Special this week on any service over " + price);
        System.out.println("Discount of " + discount);
        System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
    }


    public static void displayInfo( ) {
        System.out.println("Paradise Guitar Is A Fantastic Place To Reherse");
        System.out.println("This Rehersal Room Is Studio Based");
    }
}
```